# Angular Directive formatter/render does not update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I wrote a pretty simple [directive](http://plnkr.co/edit/HRyCyUm5PB4itglW4q57?p=preview) that turns minutes
into a range slider, as well as displaying **hours** and **minutes** next to it.
The problem is that moving the range slider does update the scope,
so Watch and Parser gets called, but Formatters/Render does not get called again, ever.

So my minutes do get updated and propagate to changing the model, but directive's "internal" **hours** and **minutes** never update.

Only if I make changes from the outside on the ng-model value.

I am not sure what's going on anymore, because similar directives all work as expected. :s

```
// Here is a shortened version
angular.module('TestApp', ['TestDirectives']);

angular
.module('TestDirectives', [])
.directive("rangeMinutes", [function RangeMinutesDirective () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        replace: true,
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: 'minutesHoursRange.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attributes, ngModelCtrl) {

            ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(function (modelValue) {
                var totalMinutes = (modelValue ? modelValue : 0);
                return {
                    totalMinutes : totalMinutes,
                    hours : Math.floor(totalMinutes/60),
                    minutes : parseInt(totalMinutes%60, 10)
                };
            });

            ngModelCtrl.$render = function () {
                if (!ngModelCtrl.$viewValue) {
                    ngModelCtrl.$viewValue = {
                        hours: 0, minutes: 0, totalMinutes: 0
                    };
                }
                scope.totalMinutes = ngModelCtrl.$viewValue.totalMinutes;
                scope.hours = Math.floor(scope.totalMinutes/60);
                scope.minutes = parseInt(scope.totalMinutes%60, 10);
            };

            scope.$watch('totalMinutes', function () {
                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue({
                  totalMinutes: scope.totalMinutes,
                  hours: scope.hours,
                  minutes: scope.minutes
                });
            });

            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
                return parseInt(viewValue.totalMinutes, 10);
            });
        }
    };
}])
.controller("TestController", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
  $scope.testObject = { testValue: 40 };
}]);
```

directive's template:

```
<div class="form-inline minutesHoursRange">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>
            <input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" class="form-control"
               data-ng-model="totalMinutes"/> {{hours}} hrs {{minutes}} mns
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

view:

```
<body data-ng-app="TestApp" data-ng-controller="TestController">
    <div data-ng-model="testObject.testValue" data-range-minutes></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't have a `$watch` over the `totalMinutes` property, just add:

```
scope.$watch('totalMinutes', function domToViewValue () {
        scope.hours = Math.floor(scope.totalMinutes/60),
        scope.minutes = parseInt(scope.totalMinutes%60, 10);
});
```

And everything works fine.

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gEz6XSPaiRDJUpQZDmNi?p=preview).

Comment: I see, so the scope was never getting updated, only the view, which was the same as before as I understand. Thank you!! :)
Update: so to clarify, I did have the watch, the problem was that it was just setting the viewValue with whatever was in DOM (as I see it), and since hours/minutes need to be changed by user, it was never actually updating these values.